# VisualStudio 2010 CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, external

I want to know , is this possible for Visual Studio 2010 to generate CSS code in external CSS file.
    By Default when i apply some style via properties it generate code in head section. i am referring that code.

Answer (score 0):

In the New Style dialog, there is the "Define in:" DropDown list:

[image]

Comment: thanks But my question is bit different. the thing i want is , when i select table or some other control and apply some style using properties explorer. visual studio generated code itself in head section of my current page . all that i want is that visual studio use external css file to save this auto generate css code. – xhah730 just now

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some boost from the [**Visual Studio Gallery**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/). Here some helpful extensions:

[Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f)

[Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83)

[CSS 3 Intellisense Schema](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210)